# Scale aspec-ratio container vertically in CSS Grid like an <img>

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I try to replicate this Demo, where the house image is scaling, when the viewport height shrinks:
https://labs.jensimmons.com/2017/01-008C.html

But instead of an `<img>`, I'd like to use a container ` instead, which also contains absolute positioned content. (can't share all the details)

See: https://jsfiddle.net/syhb7d2L/6/

The main issue is, that the `div.container` should maintain the aspect ratio (square). The classic padding-top hacks won't work, since the container width should shrink, when the height is changing.

---

I tried to use an oldschool 1x1 Pixel Image as placeholder, but since it would be within the container, it wouldn't scale correctly.

---

EDIT: As in the answer [10706764](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73490440/10706764), the CSS `aspect-ratio` property would help in the most modern browsers. Sadly only [iOS 15 and up](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio), this this wouldn't solve my problem, since we have to support iOS 12 and up (significant usage).

Answer (score 3):

The *aspect-ratio* css property will do the job:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio

You can just put the proportions (1/1 for square, 16 / 9 for panoramic...). It will work whether you base the ratio on height or width.

It is accepted in all major browsers.
[image]

```css
.container {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: red;
  width: 60%;
}
.container-height {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 60vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container-height">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This kind of works as a modern solution - thanks :)
https://jsfiddle.net/d39tmchs/

Sadly only iOS 15 (we have older version frequently). https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio

Do you have any oldschool idea for this?

Comment: I can't think of any solution using only CSS, as you said, the old trick of padding-top and absolute will not work here. 

But if you can use JS, you can just give the container a height depending on whatever you need and make the width proportianlly. If that works for you I can edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Yes, it seems, JS would be the only solution in this case. :/